# Return label and value based on order in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, sorting

Suppose I have a two column array in excel where the first column is text and the second column is numbers. I would like to have a command that would return an array sorted according to the values in the second column. I don't want to use the custom sort command because I would like to be able to update the numerical values in the second column and automatically have the sorted array updated.

Comment: Why the downvote, and what code? It's just two columns, one with text and one with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way of sorting automatically is by programming... MACROs.

You can either create a button and assign the macro to that button
OR
You put it in a selection change event which runs your macro every time a cell has changed.

up to you.

In the following code I did it for a button:

```
            Sub btnSort()
                Dim swapped As Boolean      ' Boolean value to check if the values have been swapped
                Dim boolEmpty As Boolean    ' Boolean value to check if the cell value is empty
                Dim tmp1, tmp2 As Variant   ' Temporary variable,which holds temporary value
                Dim numRows As Integer      ' Number of NON-EMPTY rows
                Dim tempArray1 As Variant   ' Holds values in column 1 with certain values
                Dim tempArray2 As Variant   ' Holds values in column 2 with numerica values

                boolEmpty = False 'Give initial value to variable; Assuming that the first checked cell is NOT EMPTY

                'Count the number of cells with actual values in them
                numRows = 0
                ctr = 1
                Do While (boolEmpty <> True)
                    'If the cell value contains something then increment variable numRows
                    If Sheet6.Cells(ctr, 1).Value > 0 Then
                        numRows = numRows + 1
                        boolEmpty = False
                        ctr = ctr + 1
                    Else
                        'if true then exit while loop
                        boolEmpty = True
                    End If
                Loop

                ReDim tempArray1(numRows) ' Re-dimensionalize the array with the appropriate size
                ReDim tempArray2(numRows) ' Re-dimensionalize the array with the appropriate size

                'Fill tempArray1 & 2 with values
                For i = 0 To numRows - 1
                    tempArray1(i) = Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
                    tempArray2(i) = Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
                Next i

                'Set variables
                swapped = True
                ctr = 0

                'If swapped remains TRUE then continue sorting the array
                Do While (swapped)
                    swapped = False
                    ctr = ctr + 1

                    'BUBBLE SORT
                    'Check if next element in array is bigger than the first one.
                    'If TRUE then swap the elements
                    'If FALSE then continue until looking through teh array until done.
                    For i = 0 To numRows - ctr
                        If tempArray2(i) > tempArray2(i + 1) Then
                            tmp1 = tempArray1(i)
                            tmp2 = tempArray2(i)

                            tempArray1(i) = tempArray1(i + 1)
                            tempArray2(i) = tempArray2(i + 1)

                            tempArray1(i + 1) = tmp1
                            tempArray2(i + 1) = tmp2

                            swapped = True
                        End If
                    Next i
                Loop

                'Redisplay the sorted array in excel sheet
                For i = 0 To UBound(tempArray2)
                    Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = tempArray1(i)
                    Sheet6.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = tempArray2(i)
                Next i
            End Sub
```

The reason I did it for a button is because if you do it the selection change event way your excel is constantly going to refresh every time you change a cell. BUT, there is a work around for this.

In the example above I used bubble sort, you can find many examples on how to understand it online somewhere.

if you want my  code to work you will have to change my sheet6.cells(....

to

your sheet number, depending where your list is found in your workbook.

In the "Count the number of cells with actual values..."
You will have to change ...Cells(ctr,1) to the row and column index where your list is found.

Hope I didn't confuse you.

Here is the other way I was talking about earlier:

```
            'If value has changed in column 2 then run macro
            Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
                If Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column < 3 Then
                    MsgBox Target.Column
                End If
            End Sub
```

This code needs to be in the same sheet. It checks to see if the value that you changed is in fact within column 2 ( Target.Column > 1 And Target.Column < 3 ) You can go a step further and add Target.row < 10 (which means, the cell that was modified is column 2 and less than row 10)

where you see msgbox is where you will copy and paste the code "bubble sort and etc.." in.

Hope this helps.